# How to specify different AWS credentials for EMR and S3 when using MRJob

Tags: mrjob

I can specify what AWS credentials to use to create an EMR cluster via environment variables. However, I would like to run a mapreduce job on another AWS user's S3 bucket for which they gave me a *different* set of AWS credentials.

Does MRJob provide a way to do this, or would I have to copy the bucket using my account first so that the bucket and EMR keys are the same?